# Is a recurve bow more accurate than a long bow?

Tags: archery, recurve-bow, long-bows

I realize that recurve bows are the "next generation" after the long bow, delivering more power for length, is there an inherent accuracy improvement with the recurve or is it just power to length?

Comment: snigger, power to length...

Comment: @Dynadin could way in here as I know he's used both.

Answer (score 6):

A recurve could be considered more accurate than a longbow due to the simple fact that longbows traditionally do not have sights, whereas a recurve does. It is however down to skill.

As a side note I will mention arrows as well. For a recurve I had carbon fiber arrows with a spiraled aluminum core, curved fletchings, and interchangeable weighed heads. For a longbow I used wooden arrows with feather fletchings.

It is much easier to be accurate with a recurve, solely down to better technology. Adjustable sights, engineered and adaptable arrows.

I started off using a recurve and later moved onto a longbow as a change. After a while I was just as accurate with the longbow as I was the recurve. It is all down to practice, a longbow just requires a little more.

Comment: Could you not use technologically advanced arrows as well on the longbow?  I.e., holding arrows constant, is it just a matter of packaging the bow?

Comment: As far as I am aware, or have ever used / seen, longbows can only be used with wooden arrows.

Comment: I can imagine that anyone shooting a longbow is doing it for historical interest.  But for the purpose of answering something like the original question, is there a *technical* or *practical* reason that state-of-the-art arrows of the correct length would not work with a long-bow?  I'm assuming the nocks will fit the longbow string, and the draw length is comparable to any other bow so it's not like you can't find arrows long enough.  (Does this merit its own question?)

Comment: I'd say it merits its own question.